# How do I limit the number of *words* in a text field input in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating an app which limits the number of words, not characters, in the field.

How do I do that?

Comment: By counting the number of spaces + 1.

Comment: @mischa, a string like `<space><space>hello<space><space>there<space><space>` would return a spurious number of spaces if you counted only spaces.

Comment: @Zabba: Hm, yeah, you are right. It was just my first thought.. I'm very bad at regular expressions, but your solution must be better.

Comment: you could use the string strip() and squeeze(" ") to remove extra whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split defaults to split on (white)space so:

```
s.split.size
```

should get the word count for you.

Should you wish to use this in a validation:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :word_count_is_less_than_5

private

  def word_count_is_less_than_5
    errors[:widget] << "too many words" if desc.split.size > 4
  end
end
```

Comment: I thought that might be what you were asking. Please see edited answer above.

Comment: @seph,  ice I am going to try it out in the next day...I think this makes sense to me....but also comparing other answer above, what do you think?

Comment: @Angela - Fair enough. `desc.scan(/\S+/).size` should work too.

Comment: @seph -- a quick question.  In your answer is "desc" assuming the attribute I want to validate on in Widget is desc (Widget.desc)?  I noticed that other validations specify the attribute in the validate statement?

Comment: @Angela - Yes, desc is the attribute you wish to validate. In the model, Widget can be left off. It's understood that you are working with a Widget.

Comment: @seph, right -- I meant, in the model, I've seen it validate :desc, :word_count_is_less_than_5 .... I just want to have some flexibility to assign the attribute in case something weird happens and have it visibile in the validate line is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to count the words and then use it in a validation:

```
def word_count(s)
  count = 0
  s.scan(/\b\S+\b/) { count = count + 1}
  count
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very simple way to do this thanks to the `:tokenizer` option. This example limits the summary field on my model to 250 words maximum.

```
validates :summary, :presence => true, :length => { 
  :maximum => 250,
  :tokenizer => lambda { |str| str.scan(/\w+/) },
  :too_long  => "Please limit your summary to %{count} words"
}
```

In this case the tokenizer splits the string into words.